# Trying to Extract Info from a Website but some values appear as null?

Tags: java, html, jsoup

I've been working and testing with JSoup for a while and this problem has bugged me for a while.

http://fx.sauder.ubc.ca/today.html

Currently this class is supposed extract info from a table from this website the only things that this program can pull from the table is

```
Code    |    Currency   |    fcu/CAD    |    fcu/USD    |    Code   |    Currency   |    fcu/CAD    |    fcu/USD
```

and all of the 3 letter codes shown on the website, but for all of the other information like values and dollar names the program shows these as null. If anyone wants to know px goes up to 34 and ay goes up to 16 as that is the size of the table I would be extracting from.

```
public String CountryHandler2(int px, int ay) throws IOException{
    String url = "http://fx.sauder.ubc.ca/today.html";
    Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
    Elements paragraphs = doc.select("body > table:nth-child(4) > tbody:nth-child(1) > tr:nth-child("+px+") > td:nth-child("+ay+") > font:nth-child(1) > b:nth-child(1)");

    System.out.println("Paragraphs " + paragraphs.text());
    if(paragraphs.hasText()){  
        return paragraphs.text();
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Please make a [mcve]. There is no way to help you here as we don't have the necessary information in the question itself. See also [ask].

Answer (score 0):

I tried this and was able to extract table data. May be you try it this way.

```
    public static void main (String [] args) throws IOException{
       Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://fx.sauder.ubc.ca/today.html").get();
       Element table = doc.select("table").get(2); //get the 3rd table
       Elements trs = table.select("tr"); //get each row of that table
       for (Element e: trs){
          System.out.println(e.text());
       }
    }
```